# How to hide sensitive data from open source projects which use continuous deployment?

Tags: virtual-machine, service, azure, github

I have a Discord bot project on GitHub which deploys automatically to Azure Web Apps. Since my project uses an API, it needs a token in a 'config.json' file. I want to share my source code, but I couldn't figure out how to make this happen without revealing sensitive data like my token.

Is there a way to not hard code it? This may be possible with a Virtual Machine but I couldn't make it work with the App Service plan.

Comment: There's really no single "right" answer to this, but... Azure provides Key Vault specifically for sensitive things like API tokens. Have you considered something like that?

Comment: Why do you have to commit your configuration file.  Why can’t it be a blank configuration file?  Has it’s been pointed out Azure has a solution for a situation like this.

Comment: @SecurityHound Since it deploys from GitHub, if there isn't a proper config file the deployment will fault.

Comment: Can’t you leave the proper configuration file on Azure and not even commit the configuration file to GitHub?